# "Intention that implies false statement of fact that", "Opinion that implies false statement of fact that"

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

Do the two that-clauses below bewilder you too? How can they be rewritten more basically?

1. 1 flummoxes me as it contains 2 "opinion"s. But I grasp that "opinion is held on reasonable grounds" modifies, and thus is the, "false statement of fact".
2. 2 flummoxes me as it contains 2 "intention"s. I grasp that

> a false statement of fact that intention/opinion is actually held = You don't actually hold that intention/opinion.

But what the heck does it mean to intend a false statement of fact that intention (opinion) is actually held?

[Richard](https://www.uclan.ac.uk/staff_profiles/richard-taylor.php) and [Damian](https://www.slaughterandmay.com/who-we-are/partners/damian-taylor/)  Taylor. [*Contract Law Directions* (6 edn 2019)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Contract-Law-Directions-Richard-Taylor/dp/0198836597/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p. 180.

[image]

Comment: I would point out that the two that's here do not have the same grammatical function.

Comment: I may have been writing about the two *thats* in "a false statement of fact that intention/opinion is actually held = You don't actually hold that intention/opinion," which I now suspect are not the two thats you're asking about.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That.  The first *that* is a [complementizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementizer) while the second is a [demonstrative adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrative).

Comment: As to the *thats* in the question title, the second and fourth are similarly complementizers, while the first and third are [relativizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#That_as_relativizer_instead_of_relative_pronoun); there seems to be controversy as to how *that* should be analyzed in such a construction, but whatever you call it, it is introducing the relative clause that describes the intention (in the first case) or opinion (in the second).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can they be rewritten more basically?

1. The opinion conveys (although not necessarily in an explicit way) fictitious grounds in order to give the false impression of being supported by the facts.
2. The actual intention differs from the expressed one.

> what the heck does it mean to intend a false statement of fact that intention (opinion) is actually held?

It means that the person tries to [mis-]lead others to think that that he has the intention at issue although he does not actually have that intention.